# How do you use a while loop to display all elements in the slice on one line separated by tabs

Tags: python, while-loop, slice

This is my homework assignment:

Write a creative program as follows to demonstrate your understanding of Python lists:
Start by making an empty list.
Use a loop to add twelve random integers between 50 and 80, inclusive, to the list.
Sort the list in descending order from highest to lowest.
Use a loop to print the sorted list elements on one line separated by single spaces.
Determine if 66 is in the list and generate some appropriate output. See SAMPLE OUTPUT.
Print the largest element in the list and the smallest element in the list.
Slice out the five elements with indexes 4 through 8 and assign to a variable.
Print the slice.
Print the total of all five elements in this slice.
Use a while loop to display all elements in the slice on one line separated by tabs.

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
71 70 67 66 62 55 53 52 52 52 51 50 
Yes, 66 is in the list at index 3
71 is the largest element
The smallest element is 50
Here is the slice [62, 55, 53, 52, 52]
The total of the slice is 274
62 55 53 52 52
```

This is the code I came up with:

```
import random
def main():
    numList = []

    for nums in range(12):
        numList.append(random.randint(50, 80))

    for nums in numList:
        print(nums, end=' ')
    print()

    if 66 in numList:
        print('Yes, 66 is in the list at index', numList.index(66))
    else:
        print('No, 66 is not in the list')

    print('The largest element is', max(numList))
    print('The smallest element is', min(numList))
    print('Here is the slice', numList[4:-3])
    print('The total of the slice is', sum(numList[4:-3]))

    count = 0

    while count < len(numList):
        print(numList[4:-3][count], end=' ')
        count += 1

main()
```

I am having trouble with the last part of this assignment:
Use a while loop to display all elements in the slice on one line separated by tabs.

The code I used seemed to work, but it gives me this error message:

My Output

```
 80 76 79 75 75 77 77 71 66 50 53 52 
    Yes, 66 is in the list at index 8
    The largest element is 80
    The smallest element is 50
    Here is the slice [75, 77, 77, 71, 66]
    The total of the slice is 366
    75 77 77 71 66 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\chapter7\program7_1.py", line 41, in
    <module>
        main()
      File "C:\Users\Isaiah\Desktop\chapter7\program7_1.py", line 38, in main
        print(numList[4:-3][count], end=' ')
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does anyone know what the issue is and how I am able to fix it?

Comment: `numList` is a list of numbers and not a list of lists. `numList[4:-3][count]` will throw error. What do you want to print here?

Comment: Hint: `numList[4:-3]` is shorter than `len(numList)`.

Comment: You've omitted part of the slice step: "Slice out the five elements with indexes 4 through 8 **and assign to a variable**." Assigning the slice to a variable will make it much easier to solve your issue. You're currently slicing repeatedly, which works, albeit very wastefully, but it makes it hard for you to make the loop to stop at the right time.

Comment: I didn't notice that part. I'll try to change that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to print a slice of numList which is `numList[4:-3]`, if lets say,`len(numList)` is 10, then, `len(numlist[4:-3])` is 3.

`while count < len(numList)` Will cause the while loop to terminate when count = 10. **But**, when count = 3, and you try to print `numList[4:-3][count]`, this will throw the `IndexError: list index out of range`, because `len(numList[4:-3])` is only 3, so its indexes are 0,1,2.

So, just change the loop termination condition to be when `count < len(numList[4:-3])`

Comment: Thank you, i completely understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can really achieve this with one liners.

Reverse sort list:

```
>>> sorted(l , reverse = True)
[71, 70, 67, 66, 62, 55, 53, 52, 52, 52, 51, 50]
```

Slice from index 4 - 8

```
>>> l[len(l)-8:len(l)-3]
[62, 55, 53, 52, 52]
```

Sum total  slice

```
>>> sum(l[len(l)-8:len(l)-3])
274
```